# CustomAction: UrlAction to open link in a new window

Tags: 2010, 2007, javascript, url, custom-action

I have added a menu item to the Personal Actions menu by creating a CustomAction like so:

```
<CustomAction
    Id="myCustomAction"
    GroupId="PersonalActions"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
    Sequence="1000"
    Title="My Link"
    Description="This is my custom link."
>
    <UrlAction Url="http://www.example.com/" />
</CustomAction>
```

I want that URL to open in a new window. I have tried this in the UrlAction,

```
<UrlAction Url="javascript:window.open('http://www.example.com/', '_blank');" />
```

but it causes the first window's content to be replaced with the text "[object]". Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: When I run it with Firebug open, the behavior is slightly different. The first window's URL changed to "javascript:window.open('http://www.example.com/', '_blank');" and its content changed to "[object Window]".

Comment: @FalakMahmood: Yes, in 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work:

```
<UrlAction Url="javascript:void(window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank'))"/>
```

Comment: Let's delete the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from the msdn page that seems to achieve what you are looking to do

```
 <CommandUIHandler Command="{4E2F5DC0-FE2C-4466-BB2D-3ED0D1917763}" CommandAction="javascript:window.open('http://www.bing.com/search?q='.concat(escape(document.title)))" />
```

And this is the link to where I found it
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500259(v=office.14).aspx#odc_sp14_ta_AddCustomActiontoDisplay_CustomActionElements

Hope its what you need

Comment: I'm not quite sure where to put the CommandUIHandler element. I'm not adding a ribbon button, which might be the problem.

Comment: It would go inplace of the <UrlAction> although UrlAction should be working