# Open SharePoint Listform in new Window/Tab

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-form

I want to edit the default View/Edit Properties Buttons in the Ribbon of Sharepoint 2013 to open the Disp/EditForm in a new Window or Tab (NOT a modal!)

Is there any way to do that or do I need to hide the default ones and create custom Buttons in the ribbon?

These two:
[picture of the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Nan.jpg)

thanks :)

ps. I tried jquery by adding a target="_blank" to a href.. of the buttons, but it just ignores those
I also tried editing the CMDUI.xml in TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML and added a CommandAction to the buttons, but it wont load those either :(

Comment: Have you tried using jquery to set the click handler to the buttons? I believe that's what's causing the default functionality, so overriding that should allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got an answer in MSDN forums:

Per my knowledge, there is no easy way to make the Ribbon button open in new window or tab, as the hyperlink is generated in backend.

As a workaround, I suggest you can create a custom Ribbon Button with the url format like below and use URLAction to make the link open in new window.

URL format for view Properties:

```
http://sp2013sps/sites/test1/Shared%20Documents/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID={ItemID}
```

URL format for edit Properties:

```
http://sp2013sps/sites/test1/Shared%20Documents/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID={ItemID}
```

Here are some detailed articles for you reference:

[CustomAction: UrlAction to open link in a new window](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55534/customaction-urlaction-to-open-link-in-a-new-window)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms458635(v=office.14).aspx